# How to trigger li of map onClick in React functional component?

Tags: reactjs

please take a look at the following component.
There is a list of `<Img`>.
When a person clicks on a specific Image, a menu opens.
This menu is the `ul`.

Now, when I click on a specific `<li>` of this menu, I get 4 console logs, one for each `li`.

How can I console.log the value of the specific clicked `<li>`?

Thank you

```
export const ActionsSelectMenu = () => {
    const [isOptionsMenuOpen, setIsOptionsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const statusList = [{ label: "aaaa", value: "Aaaa aaa aaa" }, { label: "bbb", value: "bbb bbb bb " }];
  
    const SelectMenu = () => {
      const handleSelect = (selectedItem) => {
        console.log(selectedItem)
      }
  
      return <ul className="select-field-container">
                {statusList.map((el, i) => {
                  return <li className={el.label} key={el.label} onClick={handleSelect(el.label)}>{el.value}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
  
  
    }
  
    return (
      <RowOptions>
        <Img id="optionsMenuImage" src={overflowIcon} onClick={() => setIsOptionsMenuOpen(!isOptionsMenuOpen)} />
        {isOptionsMenuOpen && <SelectMenu />}
      </RowOptions>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the `onClick` function is being called every time the map function runs because you are actually calling the function, not just referencing it. To solve this, you need to write it like this:

```
{statusList.map((el, i) => {
    return <li className={el.label} key={el.label} onClick={() => handleSelect(el.label)}>{el.value}</li>
})}
```